# Limit the Title Length on Custom Post Type Archive Page to a Set Number of Characters

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives, get-the-title

I have a custom post type 'news' and would like to limit the title character length to 42 characters on the custom post type archive page for 'news'

The following code is how the title is displayed on the archive page for this CPT

`<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>`

Do I pass a parameter into `the_title()` function, there doesn't seem to be any info suggesting you do this on the codex, or will I do it in my functions.php file?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php echo substr(get_the_title(), 0,42) ;?>
```

**Notice the *echo* and the *get_the_title*()**

This will get you the result you're looking for.

---

**Here's an alternative to consider:**

I've always found character limits cause weird word breaks that users find confusing.

WordPress has a function called `wp_trim_words` that you can use.

```
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 5, '...' ); ?>
```

5 - the number of words you want to show

'...' - the trail after the last word shown (so you could have '- cont.d' or '...read more' or something)

Comment: The client wants characters and not words, but this is a good answer so I've given it an upvote. What I want is to be able to trim/limit the characters and only add the '...' when it's more than 42 characters.